# Table header data in straight line

Tags: html, css, angularjs, html-table

I have a angular table and I want to make them in straight line how can I do that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE6b2.png)

If I add width then the th text overlapping same with nowrap also overflow x scroll is not working.Also nowrap is not working.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We're here to help you, but you have to help us to help you. Please take the time to look through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), particularly the section "Help others reproduce the problem". It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.